# Bibtex - Make Title italic, Rest Upright

Tags: bibtex, italic

Is it possible to change the behaviour/settings of bibtex so that the title (of a book, article, paper, thesis, etc.) is always italic and everyhing else (e.g. author, journal, edition, etc.) is always upright?

Basically:
[image]

Minimal working example:

Latex File:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
I cite ~\cite{Bre89}.
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{Master}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\end{document}
```

Master.bib:

```
@book {Bre89,
    AUTHOR = {Bressoud, David M.},
     TITLE = {{Factorization and Primality Testing}},
    SERIES = {Undergraduate Texts in Mathematics},
 PUBLISHER = {Springer-Verlag},
   ADDRESS = {New York},
      YEAR = {1989},
}
@article {CEP83,
    AUTHOR = {Canfield, E. R. and Erd{\H{o}}s, Paul and Pomerance, Carl},
     TITLE = {On a problem of {O}ppenheim concerning ``factorisatio
              numerorum''},
   JOURNAL = {J. Number Theory},
  FJOURNAL = {Journal of Number Theory},
    VOLUME = {17},
      YEAR = {1983},
    NUMBER = {1},
     PAGES = {1--28},
}
```

My bib-file is actually much larger, so solutions that would involve me changing every single entry would not be ideal.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Make a copy of `alpha.bst` and call it `myalpha.bst`. In `myalpha.bst`, search for

```
FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title empty$
    { "" }
    { title "t" change.case$ }
  if$
}
```

and replace it with

```
FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title empty$
    { "" }
    { title emphasize "t" change.case$ }  
  if$
}
```

<sub>Note that addition of `emphasize`.</sub>

Now search for

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { journal emphasize "journal" output.check
      format.vol.num.pages output
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}
```

and replace with

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { journal "journal" output.check
      format.vol.num.pages output
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}
```

Here, `emphasize` is removed from the line: `journal emphasize "journal" output.check` to prevent journal title from becoming emphasized.

Don't forget to use `\bibliographystyle{myalpha}`.

## Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{Master.bib}
@book {Bre89,
    AUTHOR = {Bressoud, David M.},
     TITLE = {{Factorization and Primality Testing}},
    SERIES = {Undergraduate Texts in Mathematics},
 PUBLISHER = {Springer-Verlag},
   ADDRESS = {New York},
      YEAR = {1989},
}
@article {CEP83,
    AUTHOR = {Canfield, E. R. and Erd{\H{o}}s, Paul and Pomerance, Carl},
     TITLE = {On a problem of {O}ppenheim concerning ``factorisatio
              numerorum''},
   JOURNAL = {J. Number Theory},
  FJOURNAL = {Journal of Number Theory},
    VOLUME = {17},
      YEAR = {1983},
    NUMBER = {1},
     PAGES = {1--28},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
I cite ~\cite{Bre89}.
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{Master}
\bibliographystyle{myalpha}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Follow the same strategy to add/remove emphasizing/removing emphasis as your wish.

Comment: Thanks, Harish. Your answer teaches something to me, too. +1 :-)

Comment: one follow-up question: where do i safe this new myalpha.bst? in the same folder as my tex-file or in the original folder C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\bibtex\bst ?

Comment: Ah, I left it in the original bibtex\bst folder and refreshed my Miktex settings: "Refresh FNDB" and "Update Formats". Now it works!

Comment: @Tom That is a bad idea to put your personal things in miktex folder. That is why we have the concept of `localtexmf`. Please search this site for details and use it for this case also. Or if it only for once, put the bst file in the same folder as your tex file.

Comment: @karlkoeller You made me to blush. I don't think I know as much as you do. Thanks for the kind words :)

Comment: @Tom Please see: [Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69483)

Comment: Having the same problem, I wonder **why** there is this difference: `Book and `Manual` have a title in *italics*, while `Misc` don't have it. For `Article` the name of the journal is italic, but not the title. [texlive-2017]

Answer (score 6):

One solution, if you don't want to manually create a `.bst` file on your own, is to replace the `alpha` style with the corresponding one provided by the AMS: the `amsalpha` style.

So, just replace

```
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
```

with

```
\bibliographystyle{amsalpha}
```

and you should have what you want.

Note, however, that this style changes also other things in the formatting of the bibliography entries.

Comment: Mhm, amsalpha changes more things than i would like it to. But you mentioned .bst files. Could I just use the alpha.bst as a draft for my own bst-file so that titles will always be italic?

Comment: I'm not skilled in creating `.bst` files, but the answer is yes, if you are. Otherwise, you can try to run `tex makebst` for creating your own bibliography style.