# Bibtex: how can I make the journals, books, etc titles italic using elsearticle-harv?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, italic

Is it possible to make the same change as in [Bibtex - Make Title italic, Rest Upright](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122768/bibtex-make-title-italic-rest-upright) for `elsearticle-harv.bst`?

I've made the changes in the `.bst` file, used the TDS tree.

It worked for `alpha.bst`, it just won't work for `elsarticle-harv`.

Here are the changes I made:

```
FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title empty$
    { "" }
    { title emphasize "t" change.case$ }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.sentence
  crossref missing$
{ journal "journal" output.check
format.date "year" output.check
before.all 'output.state :=
format.vol.num.pages output
}

{ format.article.crossref output.nonnull
  format.pages output
}
  if$
  format.journal.pages
  format.note output
  fin.entry
  write.url
}
```

I could really use some help on this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Copy `elsarticle-harv.bst` to the directory where your document is and rename it to `elsarticle-harv-alt.bst`.  Do not edit the original file directly because an update could overwrite it.
2. Edit `elsarticle-harv-alt.bst`.

   Change `format.title`, similar to what your showed in your question

   ```
   FUNCTION {format.title}
   { title empty$
       { "" }
       { title emphtitle "t" change.case$
       }
     if$
   }
   ```

   Add the function `emphtitle` (I added it above `emphasize`).

   ```
   FUNCTION {emphtitle}
   { duplicate$ empty$
       { pop$ "" }
       { "{\em " swap$ * "}" * }
     if$
   }
   ```

   If you are lazy, get the edited file directly from [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/87ccf97c3a323b005e9207621171b610).
3. Use the new bibliography style.

   ```
   \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
   @article{srt,
     title={Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper},
     author={Einstein, Albert},
     journal={Annalen der Physik},
     volume={322},
     number={10},
     pages={891--921},
     year={1905},
     publisher={Wiley Online Library}
   }
   \end{filecontents}

   \documentclass{elsarticle}
   \begin{document}

   \nocite{*}

   \bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv-alt}
   \bibliography{\jobname}

   \end{document}
   ```
4. ???
5. Profit

   [image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Is there a way for it to work on book titles also?