# How to make the title of a paper under "@article" italic while all the rest upright?

Tags: biblatex

Here is the code for sample.tex

```
@article{einstein,
  author =       "Albert Einstein",
  title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
                 [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
  journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
  volume =       "322",
  number =       "10",
  pages =        "891--921",
  year =         "1905",
  DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004",
  keywords =     "physics"
}

@book{dirac,
  title={The Principles of Quantum Mechanics},
  author={Paul Adrien Maurice Dirac},
  isbn={9780198520115},
  series={International series of monographs on physics},
  year={1981},
  publisher={Clarendon Press},
  keywords = {physics}
}

@misc{latexcompanion,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The \LaTeX\ Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts",
    keywords  = "latex"
}
```

And here is my code for main.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=alphabetic,
]{biblatex}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{citetitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1}
\begin{document}
\section{First section}

Items that are cited: \textit{The \LaTeX\ Companion} book \cite{latexcompanion}, The Einstein's journal paper \cite{einstein} and the Dirac's book \cite{dirac} are physics related items. Next, a citation about \textit{The \LaTeX\ Companion} book \cite{latexcompanion}.

\medskip

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

By default, my output is

[image]

My question is, how to make the title in @article (Eistein's paper in this thread) italic while all the rest upright?

In my case, since I already used the \usepackage{biblatex}, I can't use

```
\bibliographystyle{amsalpha}
```

as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122770/106851

So what is the counterpart of amsalpha in the environment of \usepackage{biblatex} so that I can make the title of a paper under "@article" italic while all the rest upright? Other means to address this are also welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using this code, which removes all formatting from the article titles:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{citetitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1}
```

you should use:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
```

I should note that this is a non-standard style, as article titles are usually upright (with or without quotation marks) and journal titles are in italics.

To make the journal title upright add:

```
 \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{journaltitle}{#1}
```

Comment: This doesn't  make the journal title upright, which doesn't look very neat

Comment: @Bernard you’re right. I’ll add that too. Thanks